# If i am using CSV file in jmeter how should i configure threads count?

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I set CSV file in jmeter via CSV data Set Config this file contains 6 usernames and passwords.
What should be number of Threads in Thread Group page.

Also what should i do if i wanted to check with 100 users?
Should i increase number of users in my CSV file or should i use number of thread?

Answer (score 0):

Answer really depends on what your test does and which load you want to inject.

But to make a realistic test, your CSV file should have as many logins as you have Virtual Users (threads in JMeters).

And you should ensure that 2 threads never use the same user (if your application does not accept it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am just confused. Can you please tell me : 1. Suppose i have 6 logins then should i have to set 6 threads count ? 2. if I want to test 100 logins so i should not use the same login as i have in CSV file (in this case i have to create more logins or just i can use the same 6 login and set thread count to 100)

Comment: 1. No it depends on the load you want to inject. 2. In general it's a bad idea to use 6 logins for 100 Virtual Users as it's not what happes in real life , but I don't know your app. If you only have 100 logins and want to simulate 100 users, then you can make your user log at start and then iterate over the scenario (OnceOnlyController) but it should reflect what happens on your app. Otherwise you should have a lot of users in CSV and set Stop thread on EOF so that 2 Threads don't share same login